# Cuda type punning - memcpy vs UB union

Tags: c++, cuda, strict-aliasing, type-punning

In non-Cuda C++ code the current suggested practice is that type punning through a memcpy should be used rather than UB via a union.  Despite it possibly causing performance issues in Debug builds, and the fact I have had to go the UB root for better performance in Release builds a few times.

What is the recommended practice in Cuda?  And will it always unfortunately call the memcpy() in Debug builds?

Comment: can you show an example of the memcpy way that results in a performance hit in a release build?

Comment: Nope as it was in an old companies code base I no longer have access to.  It was in a library of vector classes with ~VS2013 I think (Not using Cuda in that case to be clear).  One would hope in Release mode it should be ok by now though in VS2017 - but I don't know.

Comment: I think you'll find that in modern compilers the memcpy route will be the most efficient and reliable. type-punning, being UB, may even result in code simply not working - particularly when optimised.

Comment: Sure for C++, but in Cuda C++ this may well not be the case as it could maybe do 'unexpected' things like cause spills to memory due to the limitations of GPU registers being able to reinterpret things via a union or memcpy.  So punning between 32bit register sized types could have advantages for example.

Answer (score 4):

So I was curious about this and took a look in compiler explorer
https://godbolt.org/z/Cv5ozC
It seems that cuda does the full memcpy.
There is no general reccomendation but we can learn something from the c++20 standard with std::bit_cast. I think taking the implementation of std::bit_cast and change the guts to have a reinterpret cast is the best way forward. It is still undefined behavior but you are compiling for a single architecture, so it will at least be consistently undefined. And it adds a lot of idiotproofing that the undefined behavior route allows.

```
template <class To, class From, class Res = typename std::enable_if<
    (sizeof(To) == sizeof(From)) && 
    (alignof(To) == alignof(From)) &&
    std::is_trivially_copyable<From>::value &&
    std::is_trivially_copyable<To>::value,
    To>::type>
__device__ Res& bit_cast(From& src) noexcept {
    return *reinterpret_cast<To*>(&src);
}
```

There is still no good way to cast a float[4] to float4, because the type system cant represent that the pointer to the start of the array fulfills the alignment requirements of float4.

If you want more information, I got into this by watching this talk from CPPCon2019: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_qzMpk-22cc

Answer (score 2):

If you load the src into registers first, then the `memcpy` is elided, so I think the memcpy approach is still the preferred way to go to avoid UB.

```
template <class To, class From>
__device__  To bit_cast(From& src) noexcept {
    To tgt;
    From staged = src;
    memcpy(&tgt, &staged, sizeof(To));
    return tgt;
}
```

Modified version of @esdanol's example that shows the same generated code: https://cuda.godbolt.org/z/4f9n1ndEW